# How to navigate to different screen on button click in react-native android app using react-navigation

Tags: android, react-native, react-navigation

I am new to react-native. I am writing an android app. What are other options other than react-navigation to achieve navigation as I stated?. Also I would appreciate, if you could suggest links to demo for how to implement navigation for android specific app.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use react-navigation. And on button click write

```
onButtonPress() {
  this.props.navigation.navigate('Second_screen');
}
```

Comment: What if I don't want to navigate to a defined navigation in navigation configuration. Let's say for example: Add, Edit, Search buttons. when I click on them the other screen should appear but I can't define this route in my public navigation.

Answer (score 1):

### Make sure this information will help you. From this you can navigate two screens.

- You can use **react-navigation** package into your js file.
- create new **createStackNavigator** for your class or function.

For get more details regarding connection you can follow this [link](https://github.com/shivanikakrecha/ReactNativeDemo).

- You can use [Alternatives](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/tab-based-navigation.html) options of React-Navigation.

Comment: You are not giving a proper answer to the question, he ask for alternatives to react-navigation and react-navigation appears in your answer.

Could you extend more on the solution?